# Inverse of a modular group

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I understand that modular arithmetic has closure, associativity and identity, but I don't understand how you prove that Modular arithmetic has an inverse. 
Could someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: A modular residue is not required to have an inverse, only if the residue is prime, consider what is the inverse of 2 mod 8. The follow up hint is what makes primes so important for this property.